# Como conectar PDO com instâncias nomeadas do SqlServer?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, php-7

Não consigo conectar PHP 7.0.36, drive PDO sqlsrv no Ubuntu 16.04 no SQL Server 2012 quando o banco tem uma **instância nomeada**.

Quando uso a **instância padrão** funciona.

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=SERVERNAME;Database=MEUBANCO', 'MEUUSUARIO', 'MINHASENHA');
```

Porém quando uso a [instância nomeada](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/servername-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME;Database=MEUBANCO', 'MEUUSUARIO', 'MINHASENHA');
```

Aparece o erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

Observação: Esse problema não acontece no Windows 7 + PHP 7.0 ou PHP 7.1

Comment: Mas você configurou (fixou) a porta também? Porque cada instancia nomeada roda sobre sua propria porta (eu acho), logo da forma que você fez creio que ele vai tentar a porta padrão, que provavelmente não esta disponível, pois a instancia esta usando outra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que as instancias nomeadas rodem cada uma sobre a sua própria porta, se eu não me engano a porta das instancias mudam a cada vez que inicia ela, então o jeito é fixar a porta, creio que seja isto (se o servidor do banco for Windows):

> [image: sql server configuration manager]

Em **TCP Port** coloque a porta que será "fixa", um numero que não esteja sendo usado por outro serviço, e depois no PDO:

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=SERVERNAME,numero_da_porta;Database=MEUBANCO', 'MEUUSUARIO', 'MINHASENHA');
```

> No lugar de `numero_da_porta` o mesmo numero que usou na configuração.

Se o SqlServer estiver no linux creio que tenha que editar o `freetds.conf` para fixar a porta, mas realmente não entendo muito disto por isto não posso afirmar, se eu tiver me equivocado em qualquer coisa pode me avisar/comentar abaixo.

Comment: Obrigado vou verificar com a equipe de banco de dados a possibilidade de fixar o numero da porta.

Comment: Parece que esse problema é relativamente comum achei dois no link no GitHub sobre esse problema o [primeiro link](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/175) tem a lista dos problemas semelhantes. O segundo [link tem um possível solução de contorno](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/927)

Comment: Guilherme vc está certo uma solução é fixar a porta. Outra solução é detectar qual é porta, veja o link

https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/927#issuecomment-510185524

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, você está com um cliente Linux PHP para acessar o SQL Server.

Então precisa instalar no Linux o FreeTDS [http://www.freetds.org/] .

O meu arquivo de configuração do FreeTDS fica em `/usr/local/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` :

```
[mosaico]
    host = servidor.meu.dominio
; ou host = 192.168.1.2  se preferir usar o IP do servidor ao invés do nome
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.4
    client charset = UTF-8
```

A entrada nomeada como `mosaico` deverá ser usada para na chamada do banco pelo PDO. Como o PDO sabe que o driver é SQLServer, o FreeTDS fornecerá as informações adicionais. Mas usuário e senha não ficam no arquivo de config do FreeTDS .

Não estou acessando com PDO. Estou usando: [https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php]

Meu arquivo de config na aplicação PHP onde referencio a configuração do FreeTDS:

```
[ms_sql_server]
host=mosaico
user=MosaicoLeitura
password=MosaicoLeitura
```

E aqui como chamo o banco MS SQL Server:

```
final class MsSqlSrvDAOFactory extends DAOFactory
{
    private static $host = null;
    private static $user = null;
    private static $pass = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        $config         = Config::get()["ms_sql_server"];
        self::$host     = $config["host"]; //vai retornar mosaico
        self::$user     = $config["user"]; //vai retornar MosaicoLeitura
        self::$pass     = $config["password"];// também retorna MosaicoLeitura
    }

    /**
     *
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @see \DarthEv\Core\interop\dao\DAOFactory::getUteDAO()
     */
    public function getUteDAO() {
        try {
            return new MsSqlSrvUteDAO(self::$host, self::$user, self::$pass);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

A seguir instancio o driver (omiti o resto da classe para mostrar como instanciar):

```
$conn           = null;
$conn = odbc_connect(self::$host, self::$user, self::$pass);
//a consulta vai a seguir:
$rs = odbc_exec($sql, $conn);
```

Acima: $host é o nome "mosaico" , como na classe anterior, que lê os dados da configuração da aplicação.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sim o cliente é o Ubuntu 16.04, com PHP 7.0 e drive PDO. De qualquer obrigado pela dica do FreeTds

Segundo o site da [Microsoft a Instalar os drivers no Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 e 18.10](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#installing-the-drivers-on-ubuntu-1604-1804-and-1810) não faz uso do FreeTds.

Meu cliente Ubuntu 16.04 é o script [Docker usando PDO com drive sqlsrv](https://github.com/bjverde/formDocker/blob/master/ubuntu_php7.0_mssql/ubuntu_apache_php70.Dockerfile)